# Switch from elementary OS to Ubuntu

Tags: boot, ubuntu

So last week I had replaced my OS with elementary OS, no duel booting, no partitions, just full on replaced Windows with elementary OS.

That would be it, except that i'm having some issues running and even installing some pieces of software, so I wanted to switch out from elementary OS to Ubuntu, however whenever use my USB Drive or DVD it won't load straight from them like it used to with Windows, it just jumps straight into elementary OS, I can't find anything about this issue anywhere and I don't know how to resolve the issue, does anyone know what I can do?

By the way data loss isn't an issue, there's nothing on here I either can't get back easily or isn't backed up on a cloud.

Essentially what i'm asking is how to do a fresh install from elementary OS to Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried reviewing the boot device priority configurations in the BIOS menu? The USB or DVD drives should have a higher priority than the hard disk drive.

Comment: if you quit elementary, you are on the right track. Consider KDE, which works in parallel for me. Though I'm not a fan of Ubu, truth be told.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding the question and comments correctly, it sounds like the machine is booting straight into elementary OS because of the boot order dictated by the BIOS.

Depending upon the make of the machine, you can reach the Boot Manager/Menu by pressing an Fn key during the start-up process. The key that you use to access the Boot Menu will depend upon the make of your machine which if you do an internet search including the words "boot menu" followed by the make of your machine, you should find it. For instance, on my HP machine, F9 gets me to the Boot Menu while F10 gets me to the BIOS.

Once you figure out what key you need to be pressing during the start-up process, with the machine powered off, plug in your USB drive that has Ubuntu, press the power button then hit the appropriate key to get to the Boot Menu. You can then select the device you want to boot from such as the USB drive.

This information can be found in the section "Booting from the Install Drive" found in the elementary OS install instructions. These instructions would also be applicable to Ubuntu and can be found [HERE.](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#creating-an-installation-medium)

Now that we have that out of the way, what issues are you having installing software on elementary OS? Is there something we can do to help within that area that would maybe prevent you from needing to do a switch to Ubuntu?